# How to find the score of a SVM classifier in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, svm, biometrics

I am currently doing a project on multimodal biometrics (fusion at score level). So I need to get the score before fusion.
Can anyone tell me how to get the score of the particular test sample using a trained SVM classifier?

I have used the inbuilt `svmtrain` and `svmclassify` functions in MATLAB.

Comment: What do you mean by "score"? Have you looked at the contents of the structure output by `svmtrain`? Can you use those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the `svmclassify` function only outputs the label of the class and no distance (score). You will have to write your own classification function. Luckily, this is very easy: As you do have the Statistics Toolbox with `svmclassify`, you can easily look at the source code of the function with

```
edit svmclassify
```

You will see that most of the function is checking inputs etc. The important parts are scaling the data:

```
sample(:,c) = svmStruct.ScaleData.scaleFactor(c) * ...
              (sample(:,c) +  svmStruct.ScaleData.shift(c));
```

and doing the classification using a built-in function `svmdecision`:

```
outclass = svmdecision(sample,svmStruct);
```

From the definition of `svmdecision` you will see that it outputs the distance `f`, but `svmclassify` ignores it. You could therefore easily create a new function, which looks almost *exactly* like `svmclassify`, but also returns `f`:

```
1   function [outclass,f] = svmclassify(svmStruct,sample, varargin)
...
112    [outclass,f] = svmdecision(sample,svmStruct);
...
158    outclass = []; f = [];
```

You will find that `svmdecision` is a [private function](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html). To be able to call it from your function, you have to make a copy in your local folder (or any subfolder).

Comment: I have written the function as you said but, its showing error: "An error was encountered during classification.
Undefined function 'svmdecision' for input arguments of type 'struct'. "

Comment: `svmdecision` is a private function. I added this to the answer

Comment: Can you tell me how to use the private function in our own function?

Comment: You will have to make a copy of `svmdecision` in your local folder and use it normal, as you would use any function.

Comment: I have made suitable changes but here in my case I am using one versus all approach. My question is, "Can I use the same for that approach also?"

Comment: Yes sure, in One-vs-All, you train one SVM classifier for each class. Then in classification, each sample is classified with each SVM and the SVM with the highest score "wins".

Comment: yes sir, I am getting the correct class label as the output. but I want the similarity score for that particular test sample. Can I use the same method that you have mentioned above?