# svm matlab code for 4 class

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm

i write a code for 2 class svm classifier and now i want to extend it for 4 class.

I have 4 classes and some data for training and testing. I tried many MATLAB codes for this classification, but I didn't know how i can extend my code for 4 class.
i should do this work with matlab not any program like LIbsvm or svmlight or labview...

Please help me in this process.

```
trainingdata = mydata
classes =[0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;2;2;2;2;3;3;3;3]
[train, test] = crossvalind('holdOut',classes);
cp = classperf(classes);   
svmStruct = svmtrain(data(train,:),groups(train),...
'showplot',true,'boxconstraint',1e6); 
classes = svmclassify(svmStruct,data(test,:),'showplot',true); 
classperf(cp,classes,test);
```

Comment: To extend this code you'd have to implement a one-vs-all method yourself. Better would be to just use`templateSVM`, `fitcecoc` and `predict` of the latest statistical and machine learning toolbox; they have this multiclass functionality build-in.

Comment: 1-vs-1 is another possible choice. It will really help you if you create 2 wrapper functions to solve the binary classification problem, one for training and one for testing. Show us your progress and we will help you more. Btw, libsvm is a very powerful library with an easy matlab interface.

Comment: @Adriaan: i use matlab 2009b version.i want to khow wich version of matlab has this function that you told me? can you guide me to an example of the multiclass svm?

Comment: @StergiosPoularakis: i know that Libsvm is very easy and helpful in this topic.but it's a project for a lesson and they told us to do it just with matlab.can you give me an example code of multiclass svm or can you guide me how i can change my code to reach to the right conclusion?

Comment: Well, since this is a project for a class, I cannot give you code. However, I provide an answer below, where I outline the basic process for the 1-vs-1 svm multiclass approach. Hope it helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have M classes (M = 4 in your case), trainingData and trainingLabels.
There are two possible alternatives (as pointed out in the comments):
a) 1-vs-all
b) 1-vs-1

Since you need to use the matlab svm only, I would recommend the 1-vs-1 approach. The reason is that the svmclassify function does not return scores, but only the predicted class. If you necessarily want to use the 1-vs-all, you can see this post:
[How to find the score of a SVM classifier in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378722/how-to-find-the-score-in-svm-classifier-in-matlab)

Below, I assume you proceed with the 1-vs-1. To understand it, read slide 3 of this:
https://www.sec.in.tum.de/assets/lehre/ws0910/ml/slideslecture9.pdf

**In short, this is the training:**

You train M*(M-1)/2 binary SVM classifiers. In your case, it is 6 classifiers, comparing the classes 1-vs-2, 1-vs-3, 1-vs-4, 2-vs-3, 2-vs-4 and 3-vs-4.
Note that you don't need to train for 2-vs-1, as it is already covered by 1-vs-2. 
In this step, you will need to feed the svmtrain function with the right training data and labels. For instance, to train 1-vs-2, you will need only the examples and labels from these two classes.

You will also need to store the resulting 6 classifiers in a nice data structure. The simplest is multiModel{classA}{classB}.

**This is the testing for an unknown query vector:**

1) You initialize a voting vector votes = zeros(M, 1); to keep the votes for each class.

2) You classify the query vector with all 6 binary classifiers. Based on the results, you upvote the winning class, votes(winnerClassID) = votes(winnerClassID) + 1;
For instance, assume you get the following binary classification results:
1-vs-2: 2
1-vs-3: 1
1-vs-4: 1
2-vs-3: 2
2-vs-4: 2
3-vs-4: 3
The vector votes will be [2 3 1 0].

3) The class of maximum votes is the final predicted label for the query vector.
In the above example: Since class 2 has the maximum number of votes (3 votes), the result of the multiclass svm is label 2.

Comment: i try to apply the changes that you guide me about them.but i can't come to the right conclusion.can you guide me more about the changes in code? i'm in a rush and i don't have enough time and also dosn't have someone to help me about.please help me if you can.

Comment: I explained a little more the training and testing procedures. I think you will be able to code it easily, just read the answer again and follow the steps.

Answer (score 0):

LIBSVM and LIBLINEAR are two popular open source machine learning libraries, both developed at the National Taiwan University and both written in C++ though with a C API. LIBSVM implements the SMO algorithm for kernelized support vector machines (SVMs), supporting classification and regression.
Yet, you can make them in matlab too, they would give you some **mex** code that could classifier as many classes as you want. You may download toolboxes from below :
https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

also recently I found a new method **DSVM**, download and test it from elow link:
[enter link description here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48632-multiclass-svm-classifier)